# Read field value programmatically in generated report

Tags: java, c#, crystal-reports

Is it possible to read back the value of a field or formula in a generated crystal report using the Java (or C#) Crystal Reports API?

Beginning at the object:

`com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument`

Is there a method that allows evaluating the values, not just the structure of a report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without writing some automated procedure to simulate a right click and copy of the intended field. Crystal just wasn't made with this functionality in mind.

Instead, perform the exact same calculations and SQL queries in your backend. You'll find that anything your Crystal Report does, C# or Java can do it better.